# Click to open new Segment with jquery or javascripts

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Here is the Live Example what I currently have now : https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/11126587/input%20Tag%20Creation/tag.html

What I am wanting is that if I click on the "+ Add Another Segment" text it will Create same input box with same tag effect Like what currently have now(You can write Something and press the Enter To See the Tag Effect) .

**HTML**

```
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>
Input Tag
</title>
<link rel="StyleSheet" href="css/jquery.tagedit.css" type="text/css" media="all"/>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.7.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-ui-1.8.6.custom.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.autoGrowInput.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.tagedit.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {  
    // Empty List
    $( '#empty-list input.tag' ).tagedit({
        autocompleteURL: 'server/autocomplete.php'
    });

    // Edit only
    $( '#brackets input.tag').tagedit({
        autocompleteURL: 'server/autocomplete.php'
    });

    // Arrow List
    $( '#arrow input.tag' ).tagedit({
        autocompleteURL: 'server/autocomplete.php',
        autocompleteOptions: {minLength: 0}
    });

    // Custom Break Characters
    $('#custom-break input.tag').tagedit({
        autocompleteURL: 'server/autocomplete.php',
        // return, comma, space, period, semicolon
        breakKeyCodes: [ 13, 44, 32, 46, 59 ]
    });

    // Local Source
    var localJSON = [
        { "id": "1", "label": "Hazel Grouse", "value": "Hazel Grouse" },
        { "id": "2", "label": "Common Quail",   "value": "Common Quail" },
        { "id": "3", "label": "Greylag Goose", "value": "Greylag Goose" }
    ];              
    $('#local-source input.tag').tagedit({
        autocompleteOptions: {
            source: localJSON
        }
    });
    $('#local-source2 input.tag').tagedit({
        autocompleteOptions: {
            source: localJSON
        }
    });
    $('#local-source3 input.tag').tagedit({
        autocompleteOptions: {
            source: localJSON
        }
    });

    // Function Source
    $('#function-source input.tag').tagedit({
        autocompleteOptions: {
            source: function(request, response){
                var data = [
                    { "id": "1", "label": "Hazel Grouse", "value": "Hazel Grouse" },
                    { "id": "2", "label": "Common Quail",   "value": "Common Quail" },
                    { "id": "3", "label": "Greylag Goose", "value": "Greylag Goose" },
                    { "id": "4", "label": "Merlin", "value": "Merlin" },
                ];              
                return response($.ui.autocomplete.filter(data, request.term) );
            }
        }
    }); 
});
</script>
</head>

<body>
<p id="local-source" style="padding:0px; margin:0px;">
        <input type="text" name="tag[]" value="" class="tag"/>
</p>
```

+ Add Another Segment

I found this **tag** Effect from a someones Blog But I wanted to extend this with Click to Create New Segment . Also I am not used to with js Fiddle So I gave example link from my Drop Box .

If Someone can make this it would be great . If my posting format have anything Wrong please let me know if I Can help you with posting or giving  more Information .

Thanks in advance

Comment: You are going to have trouble getting questions like this answered. Take a look at StackOverflow's FAQ for information on how to ask good questions: http://stackoverflow.com/faq#questions. Jsfiddle is a good means of sharing the code because it requires you to extract a specific problem from your large project, and deal with that problem in isolation. This site is not about having others fix your code for you.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this??

```
<p id="local-source">
    <input type="text" class="tag"/>
</p>
<div id="add">
    + Add Another Segment
</div>

$(document).ready(function() {
   $('#add').on('click', function() {
      var input = '<input type="text" class="tag"/>';
       $(input).appendTo($('#local-source'));
   });
});
```

Comment: you have to change the selectors to work, i edited it to match your html. i also have a div around the add segment line, so you will have to add something similar